# Show element when #section is at top of page

Tags: html, jquery

I need to show my `#header` element as soon as the top of my `section#about` reaches the top of the page/viewport.

So in basic terms:

if `section#about` is at `offset > 1` show `#header`

I'm currently using the following jQuery to control `#header` display at 550px but I need to be more precise as larger screens will reach to different pixel measurement (so need to trigger based on when section reaches top).

```
$("#header").hide();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 550) {
        $("#header").fadeIn("slow");
    }
    else {
        $("#header").fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
                    var aboutOffset = $('#about').position();
                    var header = $("#header");
                    console.log(aboutOffset);
                    
                    $(window).scroll(function() {
                        console.log($(window).scrollTop());
                        if ($(window).scrollTop() > aboutOffset.top - header.height()) {
                            if (!header.is(':visible')) {
                                $("#header").fadeIn("slow");
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if (header.is(':visible')) {
                                $("#header").fadeOut("fast");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <header id="header" style="display: none; position: fixed;">HEADER AAAA</header>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <section id="about">
                ABOUT SECTION
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </section>
```

Comment: Nice solution thank you. The only issue now is it's showing when the #about section comes into view instead of when it reaches top of page!?

Comment: If you want to show #header when #about come to viewport when user scroll down. Use this condition:

var wHeight = $(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight;                
                    if (wHeight > aboutOffset.top) {
                        if (!header.is(':visible')) {
                            $("#header").fadeIn("slow");
                        }
                    }